# Finding spark pipeline start time from spline lineage

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spline-data-lineage-tracker

Im exploring spline to determine how much time it took for spark to execute a pipeline (from initialising spark context till writing the result). I could see

```
"timestamp":1611397050192
```

in the Spline lineage file which is actually write time. Is there any option to get Start Time of the pipeline from Spline Lineage Log?

Answer (score 0):

Spline doesn't capture the start time directly, but since Spline 0.6 the execution time is captured in the `ExecutionEvent.durationNs` property (the value is in nanoseconds). So you can calculate the start time easily as `timestamp - durationNs * 1000000`

```json
{
  planId: "1214f38d-c2c9-4155-963b-f92d91dac4fa",
  timestamp: 1614094012617,
  durationNs: 69208608168,
)
```

There is a heads up however. The current version of Spline captures *write* actions, skipping intermediate or memory only ones like `show()`, `collect()` etc. It means, for example, that if you call `cache()` somewhere of the data frame, the execution time of the subsequent *write* will be calculated from the reading cached data, as the part of the DAG preceding the `cache()` will not be triggered by the write.